# Springer Journal Submission Bibliography Item Shows "???"

Tags: bibtex, springernature

It is my first time submitting to Springer using their `sn-mathphys` style file. My bibtex entry is (as exported from Google Scholar)

> @book{artin1998galois,
> title={Galois theory},
> author={Artin, Emil and Milgram, Arthur Norton},
> volume={2},
> year={1998},
> publisher={Courier Corporation}
> }

However, there appeared a "???" in the pdf output. Looking at the .bbl file, I noticed

```
%%% 10
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Artin and Milgram}{1998}]{artin1998galois}
\begin{bbook}
\bauthor{\bsnm{Artin}, \binits{E.}},
\bauthor{\bsnm{Milgram}, \binits{A.N.}}:
\bbtitle{Galois Theory}
vol. \bseriesno{2},
pp. \bfpage{34}--\blpage{35}.
\bpublisher{Courier Corporation}, \blocation{???}
(\byear{1998})
\end{bbook}
\endbibitem
```

It looks like the style file is forcing a "location" of some sort. **What's the default procedure to proceed in this situation?**

1. Should I be looking up an address to the publisher in every such situation, or
2. should I just suppress the location somehow for this kind of item? If so, what's the "right" way to do it? (for example, it seems like doing something in the .bib is better practice than doing something to the .bbl directly so I avoid having to do it with every compilation)

(I suppose the former is more of an academia question, but the latter seems to be at least a TeX question.)